# When smoothing using a cubic regression factor smooth in R using mgcv’s gam model, how do I set the knots and k for each level of the factor smooth?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, smoothing

I’ve fit a Poisson generalized additive model (GAM) to predict the number of deaths given exposure using the R library `mgcv` and its `gam` function. Log(exposure) had been set as the offset and the model is set up the following way:

```
gam(NDeaths ~ Sex + Age +s(Age, k=6, bs=‘cr’, by= Sex)
,offset = log(Exposed)
,data = data
,family = poisson()
,knots = list(Age=c(1,6,13,24,32,41)
)
```

How can I use different `k` knots for females versus males? For example, this doesn’t work but represents conceptually what I want to do:

```
gam(NDeaths ~ Sex + Age +s(Age, k=c(6,5), bs=‘cr’, by= Sex)
,offset = log(Exposed)
,data = data
,family = poisson()
,knots = list(Age:Female=c(1,6,13,24,32,41), Age:Male =c(1,6,13,28,34)
)
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. As far as I know, the solution for a single spline is as you already show, but I don't believe there is a straightforward solution to this problem, as I tried tinkering around with it to see what was possible. I'd be curious to see if other more knowledgeable people here can comment, but the solution doesn't seem clear to me. If it's not absolutely essential, you could experiment instead with alternative spline settings to get an ideal fit (adaptive smooths, BS smooths etc), but otherwise I'm not sure what you would do here.

Comment: I tried another approach from the help mgcv section: "Specifying generalized additive models" which allowed me to vary k between male and female but I was not able to specify the knots. Here is the code in case others are rying it: 
gam(NDeaths ~ Sex + Age
    + s(Attained.Age, k = 5, bs = 'cr', by = as.numeric(Sex=='Male')) 
    + s(Attained.Age, k = 6, bs = 'cr', by = as.numeric(Sex=='Female'))    
    -1    
    ,offset = log(Exposed)
    ,data = data
    ,family = poisson()
 #   ,knots = list(Age=c(1,6,13,24,32,41), Age =c(1,6,13,28,34)
    )